# What does it mean to introduce a name into a declaration?

Tags: c++, standards, language-lawyer

According to N4567, 7.1.6.3 paragraph 2 says,

> ... If the *identifier* resolves to a class-name or enum-name, the *elaborated-type-specifier* introduces it into the declaration the same way a *simple-type-specifier* introduces its type-name...

What does it mean to introduce class-name or enum-name into a declaration **other than a declarative region**? Moreover, What exactly is the way a *simple-type-specifier* introduces its type-name?

Comment: Maybe relevant: [basic.def]/4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An *elaborated-type-specifier* can have different effects. For one, it can simply introduce a name as referring to a previous declaration. On the other hand, if the name isn't found to refer to any such declaration, it introduces the name by declaring it first.

Your quote tries to clarify that there are no further effects in the former case, similar to a *simple-type-specifier*: The type has already been declared and is just being denoted.